# Plot a function using SFML

Tags: c++, plot, sfml

I'm new to SFML. I searched Google to find a way to plot multiple points in SFML from an equation. For example, I want to plot 200 points (x,y) such that y = 2x, in the range (-10 < x < 10).

I couldn't seem to find the right functions to plot points in SFML, because most other functions are just drawing circle and other geometric shapes. If anyone know any functions for graphing in SFML, please tell me (Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMrnSa6CHfE&t=42s, not the animation, just the plotting part).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can set pixels in an `sf::Image` if that's what you are after/

Comment: @galik: I think that might work. Do you have some sample codes for it? I just want to know how they work, because there are so many libraries in SFML.

Answer (score 1):

As Galik suggested, drawing pixels onto an image is a good solution.

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
sf::Vector2u size;
sf::Image graph;
graph.create(size.x, size.y, sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
// y = 2x
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
{
    unsigned int y = 2u * x;
    if (y < size.y)
    {
        graph.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```